# How to connect to pulseaudio server from service

Tags: pulseaudio, services

I'm developing a simple app to duck audio automatically using the [pulsectl-asyncio](https://github.com/mhthies/pulsectl-asyncio) library.
I've developed the application in Python with a virtual environment, and when I run the script from the command-line, it works fine: `/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/main.py`.

The problem is running it as a service.
When I run the script as a service, I get an error: *pulsectl.pulsectl.PulseError: Failed to connect to pulseaudio server*.
The following is my service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto-ducker
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/main.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the same error when I run the script as myself through sudo: `sudo -H -u myuser bash -c '/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/main.py'`.

Why does the script run from the command-line but not as a service?
And how can I run the script as a service?

Comment: Most PulseAudio apps need a working xorg session environment (or Wayland, + dbus, etc). This is sent through environment variables. I don't know if it's possible, but if so, you need to tell systemd to inherit the necessary env variables from myuser's graphical interface

Comment: If you type `env` in the console you can see all the environment variables set for that console. Start removing them until your app stops working to narrow down which ones you need

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matias commented, the solution was to find the missing environment variables.
In my case, it was `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000`.

My final service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto-ducker
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=nicholas
Group=nicholas
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/main.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```